# Query execution time

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am new to SQL. I am trying to execute some queries on a database using PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extension. I cannot understand why the execution of the following query takes about 5 mins

```
select st_buffer(l.geom, 0.015), st_buffer(s.geom, 0.015)  
from   "road" as l,  "building" as s
```

while the execution of these queries

1) `select st_buffer(l.geom, 0.015)
   from "road" as l`

2) `select st_buffer(s.geom, 0.015) 
    from  "building" as s`

take about 300 ms for each query.

I have noticed that the execution of the query below takes a long time too.

```
select st_buffer(l.geom, 0.015)
from   "road" as l,  "building" as s
```

Moreover, I want to execute the `ST_Intersection` between the two buffer resulting from the queries. Something like this:

```
select st_intersection(st_buffer(l.geom, 0.015), st_buffer(s.geom, 0.015))
from   "road" as l,  "building" as s
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: You've requested a Cartesian product between the two tables. Of course it will take a long time. The first rule of table joins is to use the `JOIN` keyword, instead of adding tables to the `FROM` list; this will force you to consider *how* you want the table to be joined (instead of relying on the `WHERE` clause to untangle the mess) -- As a bonus, it makes it more difficult to forget the join rule in the WHERE.  Your buffer units are so tiny, I have to wonder if you're using degrees as units, in which case, you should be using the `geography` type (casting if necessary)

Comment: Did you compare the number of features in your queries? You will notice that it's not a addition of `road` and `building`.

Comment: If you want the addition of building and road in a single query, maybe you want to do a `UNION`: `SELECT ST_BUFFER(l.geom, 0.015) FROM road AS l UNION SELECT ST_BUFFER(s.geom, 0.015)
FROM building AS s` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it set up is repeating the process for all possible pairings of roads and buildings, i.e. a cartesian product. If you just want to get the buffers of the two tables into a single table then use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT
    ST_Buffer(l.geom, 0.015)
FROM
    "road" as l
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ST_Buffer(s.geom, 0.015)  
FROM
    "building" as s
```

In response to your clarified question, the way to intersect it can be done like so:

```
SELECT
    ST_Intersection(rb.geom, bb.geom) AS geom
FROM
    (SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 0.015) AS geom FROM "road") AS rb
    (SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 0.015) AS geom FROM "building") AS bb
```

However I like to put the subqueries into [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html) because I believe it improves readability, especially when the subqueries become more complex

```
WITH road_buffer AS (
    SELECT
        ST_Buffer(geom, 0.015) AS geom
    FROM
        "road"
),

building_buffer AS (
    SELECT
        ST_Buffer(geom, 0.015) AS geom
    FROM
        "building"
)

SELECT
    ST_Intersection(rb.geom, bb.geom)
FROM
    road_buffer AS rb,
    building_buffer as bb
```

Comment: In the case I want to execute an `ST_Intersection` between the result of the two queries, what is the right way?

Comment: @Ricla Please Edit the question to specify that you want the output to be an intersection, and clarify if you want a buffer of the intersection *point*, or the intersection of the buffers.

Comment: @Ricla I have updated the answer.